# Arduino Uno in Proteus send � character

Tags: java, arduino-uno

I'm writing a java program to read data from COM3 port. Data sent by Arduino [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5r9me.jpg

But in Java Program (I'm using JSSC) it return � character. If I use RXTX, it return *java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes*. I wonder how I can fix it?

This is my code

Using JSSC:

```
public class SerialTestJSSC {
private static SerialPort serialPort;

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames();

    if (portNames.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("There are no serial-ports :( You can use an emulator, such ad VSPE, to create a virtual serial port.");
        System.out.println("Press Enter to exit...");
        try {
            System.in.read();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;
    }

    // выбор порта
    System.out.println("Available com-ports:");
    for (int i = 0; i < portNames.length; i++){
        System.out.println(portNames[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("Type port name, which you want to use, and press Enter...");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String portName = in.next();

    // writing to port
    serialPort = new SerialPort(portName);
    try {
        // opening port
        serialPort.openPort();

        serialPort.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_9600,
                             SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                             SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                             SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

        serialPort.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_IN | 
                                      SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_OUT);

        serialPort.addEventListener(new PortReader(), SerialPort.MASK_RXCHAR);
        // writing string to port
        serialPort.writeString("Hurrah!!!");

        System.out.println("String wrote to port, waiting for response..");
    }
    catch (SerialPortException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error in writing data to port: " + ex);
    }
}

// receiving response from port
private static class PortReader implements SerialPortEventListener {

    @Override
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
        if(event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0) {
            try {
                // получение ответа от порта

                String receivedData = serialPort.readString(event.getEventValue());
                System.out.println("Received response from port: " + receivedData);
            }
            catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error in receiving response from port: " + ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using RXTX

```
public class SerialTest implements SerialPortEventListener {
SerialPort serialPort;
    /** The port we're normally going to use. */
private static final String PORT_NAMES[] = { 
        "COM3", // Windows
};
/**
* A BufferedReader which will be fed by a InputStreamReader 
* converting the bytes into characters 
* making the displayed results codepage independent
*/
private static BufferedReader input;
/** The output stream to the port */
private OutputStream output;
/** Milliseconds to block while waiting for port open */
private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;
/** Default bits per second for COM port. */
private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;

public void initialize() {
            // the next line is for Raspberry Pi and 
            // gets us into the while loop and was suggested here was suggested http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=81&t=32186
            //System.setProperty("gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts", "/dev/ttyACM0");

CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

//First, Find an instance of serial port as set in PORT_NAMES.
while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
        CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
        for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
            if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {
                portId = currPortId;
                break;
            }
        }
}
    if (portId == null) {
        System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
        return;
}

try {
// open serial port, and use class name for the appName.
        serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),TIME_OUT);

        // set port parameters
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,
        SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
        SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
        SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

        // open the streams
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
        output = serialPort.getOutputStream();

        // add event listeners
        serialPort.addEventListener(this);
        serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
} catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
}
}

/**
 * This should be called when you stop using the port.
 * This will prevent port locking on platforms like Linux.
 */
public synchronized void close() {
if (serialPort != null) {
        serialPort.removeEventListener();
        serialPort.close();
}
}

/**
 * Handle an event on the serial port. Read the data and print it.
 */
public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
        try {
    String inputLine=input.readLine();
    System.out.println("System "+inputLine);
        } catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
    // Ignore all the other eventTypes, but you should consider the other ones.
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
SerialTest main = new SerialTest();
main.initialize();
Thread t=new Thread() {
public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000000);} catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
    }
};
        t.start();
        System.out.println("Started");
}}
```

Comment: I am not sure how to help, but just a random hit, is there anything like you will receive serial bits, what about endianness?

Comment: probably you can have a look at ByteBuffer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html and BitSet https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html

Comment: @Vishrant i'm doing this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hteeNdA7pOo and it can receive with extract character. But with Arduino it can't. Even it only a simple Arduino code like `Serial.write("helloworld");`

Comment: Sure, I will have a look at it. But if you found the answer, please do post here. Thx.